# python win32com set outlook add in option

Tags: python, outlook, add-in, win32com

I want to automate some Outlook emails with python win32com library. My problem is, that my Outlook has an Add-in from "Secure Islands" which is used to classify the email according to the data sent in the email. I managed to set all "standard" Outlook options like recipient, subject, HTMLBody etc. but I could not find anything to set a classification provided by the Add-in.

Does anyone have experience on how to access Add-ins from python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the add-in vendor/developers for any API provided by the add-in if any. Then you can use the [COMAddIns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.comaddins) property of the Application class which returns a `COMAddIns` collection that represents all the Component Object Model (COM) add-ins currently loaded in Microsoft Outlook.

```
Private Sub CountCOMAddins()  
 MsgBox "There are " & Application.COMAddIns.Count & " COM add-ins."  
End Sub
```